# UIImage Base64 Encoding and web service issue - IOS

Tags: ios, rest, uiimage, nsdata, ios7.1

I have send an image using Base64 ENCODING to REST web service but when opened at web services end, it is shown black?

My code is shown below:

```
UIImage *image1;

NSString *encodedstring;

NSData *imagedata =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 1.0f);

encodedstring = [imagedata base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you initiate image1 with image name. Seems like image1 doesn't contain any image.
For your test, try:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some image file name"];
```

You may want to NSLog encodedstring and test it here: http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html So you can see base64 string for image is actually converted right before you send to sever.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with URL encoding + with %2B while sending the string. Replacing + with %2B would help. Your server side code will automatically replace %2B as +

Actually what happens here is when we try to send the base64 string using URL connection, Each + in the string is replaced with a blank space. This makes the string invalid and thus resulting in black image.

Hope this helps! Cheers.